# Would using SELECT FOR UPDATE and a subsequent INSERT guarantee uniqueness in text column?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a text column that I need to be unique. Because I can't put a unique constraint on the column in MySQL, I want to know if the following approach would guarantee uniqueness in the column:

1. Create a varchar column for holding the hash of the unique text column. Put a *plain INDEX* on it.
2. Start transaction
3. Use `SELECT FOR UPDATE` to see if hash exists
4. a) Use a subsequent `INSERT` if hash doesn't exist

   b) If hash exists, `SELECT` by unique text to see if it exists. If unique text does not exist, do a subsequent `INSERT`, otherwise do 'UPDATE'
5. End transaction

If I use the above approach for all inserts in that table, can that guarantee uniqueness?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that should work.  However, consider either of these one-liners:

```
INSERT IGNORE ...

INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...
```

If you are using `AUTO_INCREMENT`, be cautious about 'burning' ids.

Links:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24616315/how-to-use-insert-on-duplicate/24617186
- https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/mysql/866/insert

Comment: Forgot to mention my table actually doesn't have any unique constraints or primary keys so those `INSERT` solutions may not work for me. DB-design considerations aside, I just want to ensure my proposed solution works.

Comment: Then how does your Step 2 SELECT work???

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke about my approach - I've updated the question. Basically I have a `varchar` column that holds a hash of the unique text which has a `INDEX` that's used for the `SELECT FOR UPDATE`. Would that work?

Comment: `IGNORE` and `IODKU` need a `UNIQUE` key to hang their hats on - to know when to "ignore" or update instead of insert.  Yes, a "hash" of a long text column is viable.  (I like `MD5()`.)

Comment: Just to confirm, my updated overall approach in the question should work, right?

Comment: Your approach should work.

Comment: Follow-up question: Is isolation level `SERIALIZABLE` required for the transaction so that one session can see any newly inserted rows when doing `SELECT FOR UPDATE`? (if it's better to start a new question, I'll do so)

Comment: Again, you are working too hard.  And what if the 'newly inserted row' is not inserted until after you peak at it.  No, it won't work.  You are best off letting the transaction fail, then recover from that.  Your hash must be `UNIQUE(hash)` to guarantee uniqueness.